# How do i access branded fare information in sabre from a WPNI search

Tags: api, sabre

we are currently working to devlop a quoting tool in sabre however they have only been able to extract branded fare infomration from the graphical "Air Shopping" function. We are looking to add flight options to the quoting tool from a native WPNI search. Does anyone know if this is possible or can this brand information only be acessed through their graphical views?

We have gone back to the developer however i am looking for a 3rd party opinion

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for programmers where you ask concrete question regarding a specific issue. Unfortunately your question is too broad and lacks context to be answer properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.